# How do I add Carbon Kit to my project in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I tried to add [Carbon Kit](https://github.com/melieskubrick/CarbonKitSwift) to my project. Actually, I copied Carbon Kit folder to my project, then, in my project, I changed the **Objective-C Bridging Header** like this: **MyProject/kit/Carbon Kit Swift-Bridging-Header.h**

However, when I tried to compile&run, there was an error like this: [error secreenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5NnP.png)

How do I fix it?

EDIT: I uploaded my project to somewhere. The link is in the my comment.

Comment: did you install via pods or manual installation

Comment: manual installation...

Comment: upload your project or code i need to check bridging header

Comment: I uploaded here: http://www.megafileupload.com/ikbZ/Carbon.zip?pt=nU9zz0LQY9eSoX0yQxt8ibc3X4jiJdIymrQSMEBAPvY%3D

Comment: i don't find carbon kit folder or bridging header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your error you library you included was not proper and in build setting you had not declared the path correctly

I have uploaded you fixed project here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2csGr9uKp1DVWU2bzFKTkI5clE

[image]